# building mDNSResponder-master fails on linux machine (ubuntu 32-bit)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am building mDNSResponder-master on my linux machine (ubuntu 32-bit).
I did the following steps:
1. cd ./mDNSPosix
2. make os=linux

I get the following error message:

```
mDNSPosix.c: In function ‘mDNSPlatformTCPAccept’:
mDNSPosix.c:364:13: **error: ‘fd’ undeclared** (first use in this function)
mDNSPosix.c:364:13: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
mDNSPosix.c:359:71: warning: unused parameter ‘sd’ [-Wunused-parameter]
mDNSPosix.c: In function ‘mDNSPlatformTCPConnect’:
mDNSPosix.c:375:115: warning: unused parameter ‘hostname’ [-Wunused-parameter]
make: *** [objects/prod/mDNSPosix.c.o] Error 1
```

When I look into ‘mDNSPlatformTCPAccept() function in mDNSPosix.c, I find the following affestation: sock->fd = fd; while fd isn't a global variable so the compiler seems to have right.
How can I fix such error while I shouldn't modify the source code?
Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed when using the latest version of DNS Server provided here:
http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/mDNSResponder/
Thanks for all